# Check if another device is alive on the network based on its IP-address

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, uwp, icmp, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to write a simple UWP IoT App that is to run on Windows 10 IoT Core on a Raspberry Pi.

The App need to test if another device is currently alive on the local network. All the Apps knows about this other device is its ip address.

I see from other SO questions that Ping is not supporten because ICMP is [not supported on WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952346/is-it-possible-to-write-a-ping-class-in-c-sharp-that-will-run-within-windows-8-m). I assume this also the case on UWP?

I guess I could [create a socket and try an connect to for example port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12912412/4140832) and unless a time-out error is received then that means the device is available. However that "hack" seems a bit messy and I'm not sure that it would be solid enough to rely on.

Any other ideas for some C# UWP code that can be used for testing that a device is available and alive on a local network based on its ip address?

Comment: What will you *do* with this information? If the answer to the check is "Yes, it's connected", are you going to attempt to initiate a more complex interaction with it? If so, you may as well skip this check and go straight to the more complex interaction.

Comment: I want to use it as a simple binary check that could be used in any scenario where as a trigger. For instance if a PC is not on then start a count down timer that will turn off the light after for instance 10 minutes. But it could be anything really. The point of the matter is that I want to know is a device (i.e. an ip address) is live on the local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, ICMP is still not supported on UWP. But you could use this instead: https://github.com/christophwille/winrt-vasily (it's kind-of what you wanted to do, but already done)

Comment: This is also the conclusion I reached. It's probably the best solution for now, but the solution requires that you know what services is running on a devices and that you know what port it is running on. Using ICMP would in my view have been more elegant as this would not require that knowledge.