# Where's can I find the ping in UWP?

Tags: uwp, ping

I was expecting to see the Ping class in System.Net.Networking but it doesn't appear to be there. I've been scanning the api reference for a while, do we really not have a ping utility in UWP?

Comment: Einstein once said, that insanity is, if you are doing the same thing again, and expect that the outcome would somehow be different. Were you not happy with the answer you were getting to the [identical question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/36dc1d3a-d442-4ce6-96d7-277380d37bb6/uwpwheres-ping-in-uwp?forum=wpdevelop)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if another device is alive on the network based on its IP-address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319301/check-if-another-device-is-alive-on-the-network-based-on-its-ip-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no alternate API, ICMP is not supported in WinRT Windows.Networking.Sockets.

If you just need to check the connectivity to services on remote servers, you can try https://github.com/christophwille/winrt-vasily